# Is it normal for a question to get votes long after it was asked, with no activity in the intervening time?

Tags: discussion

On 27 May 2021 (almost three months ago at the time of this writing), I asked the question *[Why is completion of my beforeAll() function not being waited for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67714280/why-is-completion-of-my-beforeall-function-not-being-waited-for)*.  This got one answer and a few comments back and forth with the person who answered, but no votes at that time.

On 20 Aug 2021 (yesterday), I asked *[XPath: How do I find a page element which contains another element, using the full text of both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868522/xpath-how-do-i-find-a-page-element-which-contains-another-element-using-the-fu)*, which got a couple answers.

On 21 Aug 2021 (today), my question from 27 May was downvoted.

Is it normal that a question that old gets voted on?

(To be clear, I'm not asking for anything to be done; I wouldn't expect a single downvote to be reversed.  I'm more looking to learn about the behavior of Stack Overflow users as a whole, if that makes sense.)

Comment: *is it normal that a question that old gets voted on?* --> of course, this is the main purpose of SO. voting is immune to time. Anyone can vote any post at any time (up or down). This is how a post can get a lot of upvotes (or downvotes)

Comment: And... What exactly is surprising here? Your questions exist in time and space, other people exist in time and space. Sometimes they collide, and this results in voting.

Comment: Oh Yes! Some of my questions from 3 months ago have not been touched to this day.

Comment: Someone might have gone from your new question to your profile to another question & downvoted, which they are not supposed to do, but 2 such targeted-user (rather than question-feed-following or randomly found) downvotes are considered too few for the site to undo via the automatic serial downvoting undo policy.

Comment: and you get downvotes also, and you don't know why at all, that is also "normal"

Comment: 3 months isn't a particularly long time. It is normal for a post to receive votes several years after it was created.

Comment: That's Stack Overflow for you, pretty much unlike any other website. On most websites "old" data tends to just go into a dark pit never to be looked at again and thus the same things get repeated over and over again and everyone is fine with that. On Stack Overflow "old" does not imply "inactive" in the slightest. There are thousands of people sifting through it daily.

Answer (score 10):

#### Yes, that may happen.

Voting is open, and anyone with [15 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) can vote on anything at anytime (subject to the [rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899)). There are many reasons for someone to find your question. For example, someone was searching for something and then found your question, and then voted on it. I even sometimes find questions and answers from 2010 and 2009 and I vote on them depending on their quality, so it is not surprising that someone has voted on your question that was asked three months ago.

Answer (score 9):

It is not uncommon that posts receive votes long after they are posted.

This graph shows how many posts (logarithmic scale) receive a vote after X days.

[image]
<sub>*click image for the SEDE query*</sub>

And with both axis on the log10 scale (suggested by [user000001](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/828193/user000001) in a comment):

[image]
<sub>*click image for the SEDE query*</sub>

So if your post didn't receive a vote yet, hang tight for another 4,500 days or so as it still has a chance to pickup one.

Comment: What is the cause of the dropoff at the end? Exponential growth in the first half year of Stack Overflow's existence? A disproportionate number of early questions having been deleted by now? (13 years = 4748.1486 [tropical days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year))

Comment: @PeterMortensen I assume the sheer size of posts that come in every day now as opposed to how many there were in the beginning is at play here. Maybe it is better to normalize this to averages but I'm not enough into statistics and the math behind it to work that out.

Comment: The graph would be more meaningful IMO, if the x-axis was also logarithmic. As it is now, the HUGE spike near zero (about three orders of magnitude) is almost invisible.

Comment: @user000001 that is done now as well.

Comment: @rene: Thanks, that's great. Too bad I have already upvoted the answer :p

Answer (score 6):

It is not only normal that older posts are voted on, it is expected. The older the post is the more votes it should receive. The whole reason you post an answer or a question is that people in future will find it useful and upvote. If people who find it, don't find it useful, they should downvote.

The purpose of Stack Overflow is not to offer help to a single person and forget, but to create a repository of questions and answers that share the knowledge and help people struggling with similar problems in the future. Anyone can Google their issue and land on the page with your question, which has helpful answers, without having to ask the same question again.

Comment: "The older the answer is the more upvotes it should receive. The whole reason you post an answer is that people in future will find it useful and upvote." -- probably needless to say, but `s/upvote/downvote` also applies when the content isn't helpful to future visitors. OP's question seems to be a symptom of the ongoing split between "the site is about _me_ getting an answer" vs "the site is about curating a resource for future visitors". Those in the former camp tend to be the most perplexed when their content gets views/votes/comments/answers weeks, months and years after posting.

Comment: @PM2Ring I generally upvote questions because I found a useful answer under it, answers at least in my opinion are a big part of the equation.